# child element background change when hovering over parent

Tags: html, css

### Objective

I want the background color of my `<p>` (with the class of `thumb-caption`) to change when I hover over the parent container.

## Background

I have this [demo on codepen](http://codepen.io/gl_juan/pen/Aytnb) that has a hover state on the parent and on the `<p>` but the `<p>` only changes color when you hover in it directly.

[image]

### HTML

```
<div class="system-thumb">
  <a href="https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=why+is+juan+so+awesome&gws_rd=ssl" target="_blank">                            
    <p><img src="http://placehold.it/360x180"><p>
    <h2>Product</h2>                            
    <p class="thumb-caption">You should totally buy this product, yay!</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.system-thumb {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 360px;
}
.system-thumb:hover {
  outline: 1px dotted #00aba7;
}
.system-thumb .thumb-caption {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 5px;
}
.system-thumb .thumb-caption:hover {
  background-color: #00aba7;
  color: #fff;
}
.system-thumb p img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: If anyone is curious on the new working [demo](http://codepen.io/gl_juan/pen/qphwt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before:

```
.system-thumb .thumb-caption:hover {
  background-color: #00aba7;
  color: #fff;
}
```

After:

```
.system-thumb:hover .thumb-caption {
  background-color: #00aba7;
  color: #fff;
}
```

You need to assign who's going to have the event. In this case, `<p>` will be affected only if its parent is hovered. So, you need to move the `:hover` element to the parent selector.

Comment: I like that you caught that I only needed a specific `<p>` tag affected. And I also really appreciate the Before and After format that you used.

Answer (score 4):

Simple, apply the `:hover` psuedo-class to the parent element:

```
.system-thumb:hover p {
    background-color: #00aba7;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the child (`.thumb-caption`) when it's hovered (`.system-thumb:hover`)

```
.system-thumb:hover .thumb-caption {
    /* Your css codes*/
}
```

That's simple.